# Best way to replace the value in an unstructured manifest

Tags: go, kubernetes

I am trying to add namespace to the principles. I have used all the functions provided by the unstructured package(https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1/unstructured) but due to deep nesting, none of the functions fit my use case. I have tried using built in functions like `append` as well but that didn't work as well.

Here is something I tried recently:

```
        ap.Object["spec"].(map[string]interface{})["rules"].([]interface{})[0].([]interface{})[0].(map[string][map[string]]interface{})["rules"] = append(ap.Object["spec"].(map[string]interface{})["rules"].([]interface{})[0].([]interface{})[0].([]interface{}), create_principals)
```

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: canary
spec:
  rules:
  - from:
    - source:
        principals:
        - cluster.local/ns/`${metadata.namespace}`/sa/canary
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      canary: read
```

Could anyone please share some pointers around this. I am new to golang and still trying to understand how the manipulations works.

I was also hoping the the unstructured package should do the job as for a single layer nesting it works fine but for the below data it doesn't. Tried this snippet as well but it doesn't find about anything after rules.

```
unstructured.NestedSlice(ap.Object, "spec", "rules", "from", "source", "principals")
```

The end goal is to either replace the `${metadata.namespace}` or/and replace the complete value in the principals list.

Comment: `spec.rules` is an array. You should be accessing its `0`th index.

Comment: It was not the index but the query itself. Updated by question. Got it resolved. thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by properly mapping the arrays. Used this query:

> create_principals := "cluster.local/ns/" + region.Namespace +
> "/sa/" + ap.GetName()

```
    ap.Object["spec"].(map[string]interface{})["rules"].([]interface{})[0].(map[string]interface{})["from"].([]interface{})[0].(map[string]interface{})["source"].(map[string]interface{})["principals"] = append(ap.Object["spec"].(map[string]interface{})["rules"].([]interface{})[0].(map[string]interface{})["from"].([]interface{})[0].(map[string]interface{})["source"].(map[string]interface{})["principals"].([]interface{}), create_principals)
```